# Ruby: specifying value of single argument on multiple argument function with default values

Tags: ruby, function, arguments, optional-parameters

Coming from a python background, I'm used to running functions providing only the parameters that I need:

```
def f(a=1,b=2)
    print a,b

f(b=3) #prints "1 3"
```

Ruby seems to provide the same syntax for optional parameters:

```
def f(a=1, b=2)
    puts "#{a} #{b}"
end
```

But running `f(b=3)` prints `3 2` instead.

My guess is that it's evaluating `b=3` *before* the function call occurs, and passing it as the first argument.

Is this interpretation correct, and is there a way to call a function providing arbitrary arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that all arguments are evaluated prior to a method call. If you do `f(b = 3)`, then value assignment `b = 3` takes place first, whose return value is `3`, and that is used as the argument, so it is the same as doing `f(3)`. Since you provide only one argument, it will be interpreted as the first argument `a`, and the default value would be used for `b`.

You are using the wrong construction. This is the way to do it:

```
def f a: 1, b: 2
  puts "#{a} #{b}"
end
f(b: 3)
# => 1 3
```

It is using keyword arguments introduced in Ruby 2.0, as is explained in a page that Arup's answer links to.

Here is a workaround for Ruby 1.8, Ruby 1.9.

```
def f h = {}
  h[:a] ||= 1
  h[:b] ||= 2
  puts "#{h[:a]} #{h[:b]}"
end
f(:b => 3) # Ruby 1.8
f(b: 3)    # Ruby 1.9
# => 1 3
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting a syntax error on the function definition: `syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '\n' or ';'`. Is this syntax available on ruby 1.8?

Comment: @goncalopp Are you using Ruby `2.0.0` ? As *Keyword Arguments* is available there only.

Comment: @ArupRakshit No, I'm still on `1.8` (hard requirement). Is there any workaround?

Comment: Ugly, but works - thank you! I hope I'll get to use `2.0` soon

Comment: I noticed it works in 1.8 just with `f(:b => 3)`, or even `f(:b=>5, :a=>7)`. And it may be worthwhile to update the definition to `def f( h={} )` to accept no arguments

Answer (score 3):

`f(b=3)` means a local variable `b` create with value assignment as `3`, then it passed as an argument. Son in your method actual parameter `a` got value `3`, and `b` goes with its default value `2`.

Thus *running `f(b=3)` prints `3 2` instead*.

In Ruby when you are calling a method, you are just passing the values to the methods actual argument, no scope to set the value of its actual parameters from method calling area.

You should use [`Keyword Arguments`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Keyword+Arguments) to meet your need. I wouldn't write the code, as [@sawa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21704993/2767755) did it for you.